# Python dictionary contains list/set as value. how to append/add new element to it?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like:

```
myDict = { 
          'C1' : [10,20,30] 
          'C2' : [20,30,40]
         }
```

I want to update the value by appending the list.

One way I've come up with is

```
temp_list = myDict.get('C1', [])
temp_list.append(99)
myDict['C1'] = temp_list
```

But it is a little bit lengthy.

Is there a more elegant/pythonic way to do this?

I tried this, but failed:

```
myDict.get('C1',[]).append(99)
```

It does not write the new value into original list successfully. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# for lists
d = defaultdict(list)
d['C1'].append(99)

# for sets
d = defaultdict(set)
d['C1'].add(99)
```

Without it:

```
# for lists
myDict['C1'] = myDict.get('C1', []) + [99]

# for sets
myDict['C1'] = myDict.get('C1', set()) | {99}
```

Comment: Thanks! for set values, there is also a way for updating: `myDict['C1'] = myDict.get('C1', set()).update([99])`

Comment: thanks. It turns out my above comment is wrong cause `update` returns none too (so confusing). Also, your solution is buggy, as an empty set cannot be initialized by using `{}`, which gives a dictionary. so the right way may be: `myDict['C1'] = myDict.get('C1', set()) | {99}`

Answer (score 1):

You want `collections.defaultdict(list)`:

```
dd = collections.defaultdict(list)
dd['C1'].append(99)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [dict.setdefault](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method :

```
>>>myDict = {}
>>>myDict.setdefault('C1', []).append(99)
>>>myDict
{'C1' : [99]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
myDict = {
          'C1': [10,20,30],
          'C2': [20,30,40]
          }
val = 60

try:
    myDict['C1'].append(val)
except KeyError:
    myDict['C1'] = [val]
print myDict
```

Comment: what if 'C1' is not existed in myDict?

Comment: You will hit KeyError. Ok, I will update the answer with checking if key exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
if 'C1' in myDict:         
    myDict['C1'].append(99)
else:
    myDict['C1']=[99]
```

or

```
try:
    myDict['C1'].append(99)
except KeyError:
    myDict['C1']=[99]
```

Comment: it is correct. but not thinking it is better solution than my first one.